# Python Global Variable does not work

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko

Currently, I am developing some functions to do a `SSH` access to several remote devices at the same time. I encountered an issue like below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volume/Projects/SSH_Conn.py", line 51, in <module>
    SSH_Thread()
  File "/Volume/Projects/SSH_Conn.py", line 43, in SSH_Thread
    for ip in list_ip:
NameError: global name 'list_ip' is not defined
```

I am pretty sure I have created the global parameter on my codes below:

```
def ip_file():
    **global list_ip**
    ip_list_file = open('ip.txt', 'r')
    ip_list_file.seek(0)
    list_ip = ip_list_file.readlines()
    ip_list_file.close()

def ssh_conn(ip):
    date_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, port=22, username='x', password='y', look_for_keys=False, timeout=None)
    connection = ssh.invoke_shell()
    connection.send("\n")
    connection.send("ls -l\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    file_output = connection.recv(9999)
    hostname = (re.search(r'(.+)$', file_output)).group().strip('$')
    outFile = open(hostname + "-" + str(date_time) + ".txt", "w")
    outFile.write(file_output)

def SSH_Thread():
    threads_instance = []
    for ip in list_ip:
        ti = threading.Thread(target=ssh_conn, args=(ip,))
        ti.start()
        threads_instance.append(ti)

    for ti in threads_instance:
        ti.join()

SSH_Thread()
```

Is there any other parameter that I need to use in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply return the value from your function, instead of dealing with globals.

```
def ip_file():
    ip_list_file = open('ip.txt', 'r')
    ip_list_file.seek(0)
    list_ip = ip_list_file.readlines()
    ip_list_file.close()
    return list_ip  # return the value, so others can use it.
```

Then, when you want to use it, just call the function and save the result:

```
def SSH_Thread():
    threads_instance = []
    list_ip = ip_file()  # here is where you get the result back
    for ip in list_ip:
        ti = threading.Thread(target=ssh_conn, args=(ip,))
        ti.start()
        threads_instance.append(ti)

    for ti in threads_instance:
        ti.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You HAVE created the global parameter `list_ip` in the `ip_file` function, but the function **is never called**.

So a quickfix would be:

```
def SSH_Thread():
    threads_instance = []
    ip_file() # <--------------- generate the list
    for ip in list_ip:
        ti = threading.Thread(target=ssh_conn, args=(ip,))
        ti.start()
        threads_instance.append(ti)

    for ti in threads_instance:
        ti.join()
```

By the way it's better to `return` the list instead of storing the result in a global variable.

Comment: Thank you, thanks for your advice. I using return on ip_file function